# shinyWidgets updatePickerInput() server-side update (similar to updateSelectizeInput function)?

Tags: r, shiny, server-side-rendering, shinywidgets

**Does anyone know of a way to use `shinyWidgets::pickerInput()` with a large number of choices, but speed up the rendering? (similar to server-side selectize using `updateSelectizeInput()`)**

**What I'm ultimately trying to do**: have a shinyWidgets pickerInput() with a large number of choices (~1M).

**The problem**: it takes a really long time for the app to load with that many choices.

I know that one workaround is to use the `shiny::selectizeInput()` UI element, because there is a neat way to do a server-side `shiny::updateSelectInput()`, which makes both the loading of the initial UI element and the subsequent update with a bunch of options run pretty quickly (as described in [this article)](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html).

However, I really like the formatting options and flexibility that `shinyWidgets::pickerInput()` offers.

Examples:

This works and loads quickly, but uses `shiny::selectizeInput()` instead of `shinyWidgets::pickerInput()`, which I want to use.

```
library(shiny)

ui = shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::uiOutput(outputId = "ui_output")
)

server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$ui_output = shiny::renderUI({
    
    shiny::selectizeInput(
      inputId = "select",
      label = "Select:",
      choices = NULL
    )
    
  })
  
  shiny::observe({
    
    shiny::updateSelectizeInput(
      inputId = "select",
      choices = 1:1000000,
      selected = 1,
      server = TRUE
    )
    
  })
  
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When trying to do the same with `shinyWidgets::pickerInput()`, I tried both loading the choices directly into the UI initially:

```
server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$ui_output = shiny::renderUI({
    
    shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
      inputId = "select",
      label = "Select:",
      choices = 1:1000000
    )
    
  })
  
}
```

And also trying to same logic that I used in the first example, which is to initially load the UI object with `choices = NULL`, and then have a `shiny::observe()` call that updates the UI element's choices (this works, but is really slow):

```
server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$ui_output = shiny::renderUI({
    
    shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
      inputId = "select",
      label = "Select:",
      choices = NULL
    )
    
  })
  
  shiny::observe({
    
    shinyWidgets::updatePickerInput(
      session = getDefaultReactiveDomain(),
      inputId = "select",
      choices = 1:1000000,
      selected = 1
    )
    
  })
  
}
```

Comment: This is still an [open issue](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/184) in shinyWidgets repo. The serverside updatePickerInput is not implemented yet but requested a lot.

Comment: @bretauv ah, bummer. Thanks for the head up on that :)